# Failed to open file '{dump.sql}', error: 13 Windows 10

Tags: mysql, windows

I have installed XAMPP with PHP 7.2.23 and MySql v8 and want to import database dump on Windows 10

I used this commands in Command promt running by Administrator:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root

mysql> USE my_database
mysql> SOURCE C:/Users/user/Downloads/dumps/dump.sql
```

root user has ALL PRIVILEGIES

But I see this error:

```
Failed to open file 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\dumps\dump.sql', error: 13
```

Comment: "error: 13" suggests you lack permissions to access the file (or any of the directories along its path).

Comment: Yes I understand this, but how I can give access to make this import?

Comment: @mustaccio may be I need to change user in mysql configuration?

Comment: MySQL privileges and OS privileges are independent of one another.